# How to transfer token to a burn wallet when swapped back

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, swaps

I want to transfer a percentage of my token to a burn wallet, everytime they are sold INTO the uniswap in exchange for any other Token/ETH, without reducing the payout to the sender.

So lets say Uniswap LP holds 1000 Token at a price of 1 eth each and a total LP of 1000 ETH. Holder sells 100 Token, he is supposed to receive 100 ETH, but only 90 Token go into the LP, the other 10 should be send to x Wallet.

How to execute that?
Do i need to define it for each possible LP or is there a global way to detect this kind of transaction for any possible swap provider?

Answer (score 1):

No way to detect that kind of transaction for any possible swap provider.
You should define it for each possible LP on `transfer` function on token smart contract.

```
// store addresses that a automatic market maker pairs.
mapping (address => bool) public automatedMarketMakerPairs;

function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override {
    //if any account is trying to sell tokens
    if(automatedMarketMakerPairs[to]) {
        //add the logic here
    }
}
```